# how to feed a tibble to spacyr?

Tags: r, spacy, quanteda

Consider this simple example

```
bogustib <- tibble(doc_id = c(1,2,3),
                   text = c('bug', 'one love', '838383838'))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  doc_id text     
   <dbl> <chr>    
1      1 bug      
2      2 one love 
3      3 838383838
```

This `tibble` is called `bogustib` because I know `spacyr` will fail on row 3.

```
> spacy_parse('838383838', lemma = FALSE, entity = TRUE, nounphrase = TRUE)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "doc_id", value = "text1") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

so, naturally, feeding the `tibble` to `spacyr` will fail as well

```
spacy_parse(bogustib, lemma = FALSE, entity = TRUE, nounphrase = TRUE)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "doc_id", value = "3") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

My question is: I think I can avoid this issue by calling `spacy_parse` row by row.

However, this looks inefficient and I would like to use the `multithread` argument of `spacyr` to speed up the computation over my large `tibble`.

Is there any solution here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it does not happen in my environment. In my environment, the output is like:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(spacyr)

bogustib <- tibble(doc_id = c(1,2,3),
                   text = c('bug', 'one love', '838383838'))

spacy_parse(bogustib)

spacy_parse('838383838', lemma = FALSE, entity = TRUE, nounphrase = TRUE)
## No noun phrase found in documents.
##   doc_id sentence_id token_id     token pos     entity
## 1  text1           1        1 838383838 NUM CARDINAL_B
```

To get this result, I used the latest master on github. However, I was able to reproduce your error when I ran with the CRAN version of spacyr. I'm sure that I fixed the bug a while ago, but that seems not reflected on CRAN version. We will try to update the CRAN asap.

In the meantime, you can:

```r
devtools::install_github('quanteda/spacyr')
```

Or zip download the repo and run:

```r
devtools::install('******')
```

`****` is the path to the unzipped repository.